# Xcode does not display the list of provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have some issue with Xcode 6.3, in below image you can show that there is and no selection provided to select provisional profile name or application ID like (Automatic, or any other app Id name) and also not able to get list of provisional profiles which was available. How can I resolve this?

[image]

Currently I am set provisional profile name manually like below.

[image]

Comment: double click the downloaded profile file to install and then add your apple developer account to Xcode and it will work

Comment: Not working, are you understand my question ?

Comment: Please check whether the keychain access developement & distribution certificate installed or not,or else expired

Comment: Fortunately everything is now working fine but I don't know how this was an enable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First go to Xcode > Preferences:

[image]

Login with the developer account with the profiles you are trying to get to show up. When you do, highlight the account and press "View Details":

[image]

After that, press the refresh button to make sure your profiles are there. Then go back to Code Signing in Xcode. Your profiles should show up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add your developer account in team section.

You can find team section in Project Target Options.

Once you will add it, hopefully you will get everything in build setting.

Comment: Quit the Xcode & restart it out.. Then see what happen?

Answer (score 0):

follow steps below

1)xcode -> preference -> accounts

click on account name -> view details(on right side)
http://prntscr.com/7z4nve
you can see like this and click on refresh button below left side

hope works

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't have the certificate's private key installed in your system.

You need to follow these steps:

- Whichever certificate it is, whether it is developer or distribution certification, which you are using for you application, install the private key of that certificate on to you system.
- Install the provisioning profile.
- The certificates will be now visible in the drop down of "Code Signing Entity"
- Select you certificate

Now you provisioning profile will be visible in the profile's drop down.

Please make sure that profile is created with the same certificate.

Comment: I was working with iOS since last 5 year I know this everything. This is not this issue, Actually issue is solved. But even I don't know How this was done. :)

Answer (score 0):

For me it was solved by having the account owner login to the apple developer account and agree to changed Apple Developer Licensing Agreement. I can't imagine a reason why Apple doesn't show any message why the provisioning profile couldn't be imported.